# Missing JSON field causes crashes?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

My Code goes like this:

```
    using (StreamReader streamReader1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string resultString = streamReader1.ReadToEnd();
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(resultString));
        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
        RootObject myBook = (RootObject)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Shops.ItemsSource = myBook.SearchResponse.Spell.Results); }

  public class Query
    {
        public string SearchTerms { get; set; }
    }


    public class Result
    {   [DataMember(IsRequired=false)]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Spell
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
        public int Total { get; set; }
        [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
        public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchResponse
    {
        public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public Query Query { get; set; }
        public Spell Spell { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public SearchResponse SearchResponse { get; set; }
    }
```

IF JSON DATA EXISTS

```
  {"SearchResponse":{"Version":"2.0","Query":{"SearchTerms":"mispell"},"Spell":{"Total":1,"Results":[{"Value":"misspell"}]}}}
```

IF JSON DATA DOES NOT EXIST

```
  {"SearchResponse":{"Version":"2.0","Query":{"SearchTerms":"mispel"}}}
```

The thing is, if Bing doesn't detect a wrong word, it crashes and gives me an error like NullReferenceException. I have tried to do an IF statement looking at the stream for if it's value is blank but doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you receive a JSON answer without the *Spell* part, the `Spell` property in `SearchResponse` will be *null*. If it's *null*, you may not dereference it like this:

```
myBook.SearchResponse.Spell.Results
```

(This hasn't anything to do with JSON. It's how C# works.)

So instead of:

```
Shops.ItemsSource = myBook.SearchResponse.Spell.Results
```

you probably want to write:

```
if (myBook.SearchResponse.Spell = null)
    Shops.ItemsSource = myBook.SearchResponse.Spell.Results;
else
    Shops.ItemsSource = new List<Result>();
```

For your next question: It would be very helpful if your questions would show the exact error message including the stack trace (or at least the exact line where it occurred).

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataMember(IsRequired=false)], MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.isrequired.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve it, still gives me "NullReferenceException".

Comment: can you post your RootObject class and json data?

Comment: I have added the JSON and RootObject.